# Switching pages loading the same left menu

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm new to `Xamarin` and I don't understand too much things.
I've created an android app with the preinstalled left menu (hamburger menu) including navigation view. My `content_page.xml` is linked to `MainActivity.cs` and I run my code there. Now I want to create another page. So I add a layout element (like `content_page`) called `second_content_page.xml` and I link it to a new activity called `SecondActivity.cs`. Code behind works and I got no problems as far.
The problem is the second content page which doesn't show the menu items (there are lots of layouts about it). So I've tried to copy the code from `MainAcitivity's` `OnCreate` method:

```
   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        //ToolBar
        AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_open, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.SyncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
        navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

But I run into many errors related to the toolbar that (as VS says) is loaded two times, so I thought this way to load the same menu was incorrect.

My question is: how to switch pages in the correct way using xml pages and not xaml?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use FlyoutPage, it contains flyout page and detail page and the menu will always display if you what.

Here is a guide about it:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage

And here is an sample link:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/Navigation/FlyoutPage